# Is there a way to indent forward in text editor?

Tags: text-editor

I would like to know if there's a way to indent forward multiple lines. For indent back warding, I know that I have to select multiple codes and press tab. However, is there a way to do the opposite? On a word document, I usually did tab + delete/backspace to move bullet points forward but it seems like that's not the case for text editor.

Thank you guys in advance!

Comment: This really depends on what text editor you use, but Shift + Tab usually works.

Comment: This question doesn't seem to be about programming

Comment: You failed to provide a key piece of information; namely which text editor you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most Editors use Shift+Tab to backward indent text. Try this shortcut.

If your Editor does not provide this feature, try Notepad++ (Windows). This  editor is a free lightweight editor for coding-tasks and it offers features like this backward  indent and many many more.

On  Linux systems Geany is comparable with Notepad++.